# How do I programmatically set the hidden property for a Tab (button)

Tags: extjs, properties, set

I have an Ext TabPanel, and I am trying to set the hidden property for one of the Tabs, programmatically. I am able to select the object and call methods such as disable() and enable() but so far have been unable to find a means by which I can manipulate the Tab's 'hidden' property.

The Tab is defined as

```
{
    id: "view-task",     
    hidden: false,
    title: "View"
}
```

and the code attempting to manipulate it

```
twin = (  Ext.getCmp('view-task'));
twin.disable();
```

The above call to disable works, so the component is being correctly selected but I do not know how to manipulate the hidden property.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

N. Euzebe

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
    items: [{
        itemId: 'home',
        contentEl:'script', 
        title: 'Short Text',
        closable: true
    }]
});
tabs.child('#home').tab.hide();
```

You can find this code in examples on the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) page

Answer (score 2):

You haven't explained which version of ExtJS you're using. But in version 3.x you can do the following (I don't know, but it might also work in ExtJS 4.x):

```
var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('myTabPanel');
var tabToHide = Ext.getCmp('myTab');
tabPanel.hideTabStripItem(tabToHide);
```

To show the tab again:

```
tabPanel.unhideTabStripItem(tabToHide);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Also, it said that method does not exist (probably due do the version difference)